# Prestashop template extends in child theme

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm beginning to use PrestaShop so I've installed a 1.7.7.1 with the classic theme.

I have created a child theme which uses the classic theme as parent and selected it through the admin page. The website shows normally.

When creating a child theme, I'm trying to modify a small part of the product page by creating a product.tpl page in the child theme. I then try to extends the parent product page but this doesn't work, the product page just stays blank.

Here is the line in my **child-theme/template/catalog/product.tpl** file:

```
{extends file='parent:catalog/product.tpl'}
```

Doing so, I should see the product page as it is with the classic theme.

I've watched some tutorials and I've done the exacts same steps and it is not working properly for me. I can't figure out what I did wrong.

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1):

Ok, that was easy, I solved my problem by deactivating the cache and choosing "Recompile templates if the files have been updated" in the advanced parameters.